# Postgres connection fails, uses system user instead the one provided in database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to run some rspec tests for my Rails app but I get a Postgres connection error. It uses my system user, instead of the one I provided for the dev environement, in database.yml. Could someone have a look please? And maybe give me some doc to help me understand how it searches for the user role?

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/helpers/navigation_helper_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError:
FATAL:  role "yopeso_internship" does not exist
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/helpers/navigation_helper_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

# --- Caused by: ---
# PG::ConnectionBad:
#   FATAL:  role "yopeso_internship" does not exist
#   ./spec/rails_helper.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: Please, show us your `database.yml` (without the passwords/secrets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `database.yml` you are not providing valid credentials for your `test environment` like you did for `development`.

Also show your `database.yml`.